# Travel within Schengen countries - passport control

Tags: schengen, international-travel

I am an Indian citizen planning to visit Munich for the Oktoberfest for 3-4 days and then go to Austria for a weeklong spa therapy. I will be thus flying from India to Munich first up where I shall get my passport controls done at Munich and then upon the end of the journey, would be flying back directly from Austria to India. Since 7 of my 10-day stay would be in Austria, guess I will have to apply for the Schengen visa at the Austrian embassy.

My question is this: Once the first leg of my stay at Munich is over, I plan to fly from Munich, Germany to Klugenfurt, Austria via Vienna, Austria. So would I again have to go through immigration and get a passport stamp upon entering Austria? Am asking because I would already have got a stamp on entering Munich. And if the answer is “yes”, do I have to get the entry stamp at Vienna while waiting for my connecting flight or could I do this at Klagenfurt which is my destination?

Comment: Please don't use all caps in your title.  I edited it.

Comment: The answer to this may be different by the time you travel, but for the moment you will not need to clear immigration if your flight originated within the zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is definitely no stamping between Austria and Germany in one direction or the other, no matter how you travel.

Usually, I would also say that you are unlikely to even talk to a police officer but, increasingly, there are “random” checks, especially on trains and other land borders but perhaps more frequently in the other direction (Austria to Germany). It's difficult to quantify that exactly but many anecdotal reports also suggest that border police in many European countries take a special interests in people who look “non-European” so if you “look Indian”, you might have to face that, sadly.

By plane, I would still expect no control whatsoever. But if there is one, showing your passport and Schengen visa/German entry stamp will be enough and your documents should not be stamped again in either Vienna or Klagenfurt.

Comment: Thanks “Relaxed”-

So does that mean that when I fly back from Salzburg to India via Frankfurt, the immigration official at Salzburg airport would not look for an “Austria entry” stamp while putting the exit stamp on my documents? Basically meaning he would be happy with just the “German” entry stamp.

And also, while after landing in Frankfurt from Salzburg and waiting for my final flight back home to India, do I need any other validation at Frankfurt airport either or should I just board the flight to India?

Sorry for asking- this is my first time ever, so want to ensure I don’t go wrong ☺

Comment: @user34785 Right, there's no way a Austrian stamp is necessary, because depending on how you´re coming from D to A, a road sign that Austria begins there might be all you see from the border, so you can´t get a stamp at all in such situations

Comment: Btw., its "Kl**a**genfurt", and you have to have some ID always with you (not in the hotel etc.). And in Klagenfurt, in the wrong locations, you could experience random checks even without border (well, in theory everywhere, not just Klagenfurt). In the last time, too many problematic things happened, and the police organization got a bit tense.

Comment: @user34785 No, if you would exit the Schengen area directly from Austria to India, an Austrian border guard should look for a Schengen entry stamp, if (s)he bothers at all. But in your scenario, the exit formalities will be in Frankfurt again so you will get both the entry and the exit stamp from the German federal police, even though you have an Austrian visa. That's perfectly normal.